# Тире или скобки?

Tags: тире

Правильны оба варианта?

> Сейчас пришлю я видео — когда загрузится.

> Сейчас пришлю я видео (когда загрузится).

Comment: Окрошку в оливье переделывать никому в голову не приходит. Однако...

Comment: Окрошка и оливье? Да, здесь действительно странное сопоставление двух решений. Поэтому отвечающим надо было объяснить, что между ними общего. Ведь можно подумать, что буква О.  В то же время  что-то общее все-таки есть. Получается такая суперзадача))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Сейчас** пришлю я видео — **когда загрузится*** — тире обособляет пояснительный член предложения; он поясняет слово *сейчас*;

*Сейчас пришлю я видео (когда загрузится)* — вставная конструкция.

Comment: А где здесь пояснительный член предложения? Когда загрузится  — это больше на придаточное предложение похоже. И в целом ответ не выглядит образцовым — тема не раскрыта. Почему одна и та же семантика сообщения обозначена двумя вариантами? Вставная конструкция и пояснительный член предложения — что между ними общего?  И оформление текста ответа странное: в первом предложении два тире.  В целом все это похоже на ту же систему:  короткий вопрос — короткий ответ — ответ принят. Не хватает продуманности темы и ее качественного раскрытия.

Comment: Добавьте, пжста, ссылку на правило  для предложения (1).  Иначе неясно, почему пояснение обособляется тире.

Answer (score -1):

Вариант со скобками — для письменного послания, с тире — для устного.

Так что оба верны.

Comment: Галина, оба знака графические. Как понять для устного?

Comment: Сержик, не понимаю вопроса! "Устный" - это когда произносимое передаётся на письме как прямая речь.

Comment: Галина, если честно, в нашем примере, что со скобками, что без скобок — нет прямой речи. Т.е. тире это прямая речь, а скобки — косвенная? Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Нет, Сержик, значит, я неверно рассказала. Тире и скобки для данного предложения - стилистические знаки. Тире - разговорное, эмоциональное, скобки ближе к официальному изложению.

Comment: А-а, понятно, спасибо.